# How opaque is stacked opacity in CSS?

Tags: html, css, opacity

If I have something like the following:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

What will the final alpha value be in the `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

80%.

Basically, the first layer is 60%.  The second layer is 50% on top of the remainder, so 50% of 40% == 20%...  60%+20% = 80%.

If you added another 25% div on top, you'd be at 85% opaque:
  0.80 + ((1-.80)*.25) = 0.85%.

I'm sure there is some sort of algorithmic function for handling all of the layers together, but it is easy enough to calculate with a bit of script and a loop.